# count lines and create new file

Tags: python

So basically I have to call the text file, and create the new file while adding some strings.

For example if my input text is:

Hello

World

Nice to Meet You

my output text has to be:

1: Hello

2: World

3: Nice to Meet You

Below is the code that I have been trying to figure out. When I try it, there is no error, but it does not create the new file too.

```
with open('filetext') as f:
    content=f.readlines()   
    for count in f:
        count+=1
        with open('newfiletext', 'a+') as f:     
        f.write(counts)
        f.write(': ')
        f.write(content)
        f.write('\n')
```

I appreciate if I can get a help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Your indentation in the last block is off. 2) For your sanity give your input and output variables different names.

Comment: oh. acutally there is indentation in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

textfile:

```
Hello
World
Nice to Meet You
```

code:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i , line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        print "{0}:{1}".format(i+1,line)
```

output:

```
1:Hello

2:World

3:Nice to Meet You
```

then you can store in string and write the to file or another file

Comment: Your output is almost correct, but the OP wanted to start counting from one not zero.

Comment: one minute will change it @leaf

Comment: i am sorry, but how does "{0}:{1}" works? I know .format(i,line) tho

Comment: {0} mean first argument passed to format function and {1} the second and so on @user7016438

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining! @Hisham Karam

Answer (score 1):

First you open the file:

```
with open('filetext') as f:
```

Then you read the whole thing into a list:

```
content=f.readlines()
```

Then you attempt to iterate over the now-empty file object:

```
for count in f:
```

Since it's empty, nothing in the following block will execute, even once. Make sure you keep track of variable names and use a unique one for each unique object you want to manipulate - notably, `f` and `count` are reused when they shouldn't be:

```
with open('filetext') as f, open('newfiletext', 'a+') as output:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        output.write(count)
        output.write(': ')
        output.write(line)
```

Comment: oh my god! I didn'tt know I can open two files at the same time! It makes my life much easier.

Comment: actually I just tried your code, but the newfiletext is blank... T_T but still thank you for your time